# Working with pandas on python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on an environment with python 2.7 and need to use pandas. While researching and studying documentation, I can't seem to see any distinction between pandas 3.6 vs 2.7 code. Is there any distinction between pandas running on 2.7 vs 3.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, pandas spends some effort to make the package work identically across different Python versions. To that effect, there is a whole [`compat`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/compat/__init__.py) layer hidden within Pandas. So apart from how you inject data in and work with data coming out of DataFrames, pandas should be the most invariant part in all that.